# Input statement is not reading all the datalines

Tags: sas

I'm trying to read in some raw data using datalines...

```
data Exp_data;
INPUT a: 2. b: 2. DATE1: MMDDYY10. DATE2: MMDDYY10.;
FORMAT DATE1 DATE9. DATE2 DATE9.;
datalines;
27 93 03/16/2008 03/17/2008
27 93 03/17/2009 03/19/2009
68 68
55 55
46 68
34 34
45 67
56 75
34 34
34 34
;RUN;
```

But this code is reading data until 6 th row. I couldn't figure out where I'm doing mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add this line before your input statement.

```
infile datalines missover;
```

As of the third row you don't have 4 values, so SAS needs to know what to do with the missing values. Missover tells sas to set the remaining values to missing.